# Project successfully links to DLL in 32 bits, but not in 64 bits

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-2015, dllexport, unresolved-external

Something that's probably as old as the world itself (if you allow me that slight exaggeration).

I was compiling a DLL in Visual Studio Express 2015 in 32 bits and testing it in a dummy project in 32 bits as well.

Comes someone, who wants it in 64 bits. I go in my project settings and change all to x64 (DLL and dummy app). But now the compiling of the dummy app fails because the symbols that are used in the dummy project and should be found in the DLL fail to resolve at linking time. I know x64 doesn't decorate symbol names as x86 does, but who cares actually ? Both my dummy project AND my DLL are now compiled in x64 (I checked).

A couple infos to my architecture : both sub-projects (compilation units) are part of a common "solution" (as it is called in Visual Studio) and therefore share a common configuration (I checked, x64 at solution-level implies x64 at dummy-level AND DLL-level, as both /MACHINE arguments are set to x64 in the respective linker options, and the DLL compiles fine on its own with that).
In my DLL, the methods are declared as __declspec(dllexport), and so I don't use a .def file. It has worked until now, and still works in Win32 mode. The same header file is then reused for the dummy project, the __declspec(dllexport) now being undefined. Final info : the DLL contains C++ code, but the methods that are exported as C methods, declared as extern "C" when __cplusplus is defined (which is the case here) (this the typical trick).

By the way, yes, the config that was on and worked until now was "Release, Win32" and not x86. But both work equally well in Release mode. In "Debug" mode however nothing works, neither x86 (or Win32) nor x64, with the same error (at linking time, all externals used in the dummy fail to resolve). Except that in Win32 or x86, it mentions the symbols with a leading underscore.

This last element set me up the trail of symbol decoration in x86, which doesn't happen in x64. But again, shouldn't matter, right ?

Thanks in advance for any wise tips !

Charles

EDIT 1 : I am interested in Release mode, we can handle Debug mode later.

EDIT 2 : I see that my DLL has additional dependencies at linking time, most of which have 32 in their name: kernel32.lib, user32.lib, ... But it still compiles in 64 bits. Is the DLL however automatically degraded to 32-bits without warning me because of that ?

Comment: How are you using the dll in your client application? I mean when you use the dll it should be `__declspec(dllimport)`. That is why a macro is usually used for this that switches from `__declspec(dllexport)` to `__declspec(dllimport)` depending on if you are compiling the dll or using the dll.

Comment: Like I said, I leave the special macro to be undefined, and it works with Win32/x86. Why shouldn't it with x64 ? All it changes anyhow is the name of the symbol as reported in the error message : It now has a `__imp_` prefix decoration.

Comment: Are you setting the correct path to your dependencies? Keep in mind these needs to be set for each architecture. You can find this by right clicking in project -> properties -> Reference paths

Comment: I can find no such "Reference path" property menu. All I have that is specific to my DLL is an additional dependency in the Linker properties, which simply states the name of the LIB-file (without any further path).

Comment: Do the 32 and 64 bits projects have different temp directory / target directory ? Do the dummy project tries to link the good (64) lib file ?

Comment: (Most of) the standard *Win* libs end with *32*, but that doesn't mean they're 32bit (it's a legacy since *Win* switched from 16 to 32 bit). Make sure that the *Platform/Configuration* pair whose properties you check is the same one used for building. the `dllexport`ed symbols in the dll must be `dllimport`ed in the app. Check your configurations if the lib file is included in linker dependencies, also make sure you have the correct paths set. Last thing, clean the solution from time to time.